# iOS 8 : Mapkit error throws an : Must call -[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization]

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8

In iOS 8.3 with xCode 6.3.2, when I'm launching Map, it throws the following error:

```
Trying to start MapKit location updates without prompting for location authorization. Must call -[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization] or -[CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization] first.
```

I have done everything and follow every step to launch a map in ios8 app, here is my code for this:

```
//viewcontroller default function set mapview and a function to find user current location.   
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [[self otlMapView] setShowsUserLocation:YES];
    self.otlMapView.delegate = self;

    [self updateUserCurrentLocation];
}

//this function is used to fine the user current location.
-(void)updateUserCurrentLocation
{
    // Create a location manager
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    // Set a delegate to receive location callbacks
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])
    {
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }

    // Start the location manager
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}

#pragma mark Location Callback Method

// Wait for location callbacks
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    NSLog(@"Current Location%@", [locations lastObject]);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you add requestWhenInUseAuthorization key in info.plist ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you've correctly set up your Info.plist already. Then try something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [self updateUserCurrentLocation];
  }

- (void)updateUserCurrentLocation {
  if (nil == locationManager) {
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
  }

  locationManager.delegate = self;

  // This part was added due to a location authorization issue on iOS8
  // See more at: http://nevan.net/2014/09/core-location-manager-changes-in-ios-8/
  if ([self._locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
    [self._locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
  }

  self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;

  [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

  CLLocation *currentLocation = locationManager.location;
  if (currentLocation) {
    PAWAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.currentLocation = currentLocation;
  }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.

Yes, I have added this parameter into plist NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription.

I'm still facing issue with your code as well.

Pleas suggest.

Comment: What if you add both following keys in your plist:
- NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
- NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription

Comment: Do you still have these 2 line in  viewDidLoad?
`[[self otlMapView] setShowsUserLocation:YES];`
`self.otlMapView.delegate = self;`
What are they for?

Comment: Yes, I have added both keys into plist : - NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription - NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription and I removed these lines as well [[self otlMapView] setShowsUserLocation:YES]; self.otlMapView.delegate = self;. But still not working.

Comment: Thanks. I found the solution, info.plist was not updating to the bundle. Now, I have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You should make sure to call

```
 [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
```

before calling

```
 [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Also, have you set up your Info.plist?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have this key in your info.plist, 
"Privacy - Location Usage Description",

if yes remove this and retain the "When in use" key. it should then work.